# How to add and remove random bit padding in Python

Tags: python, list, padding

**UPDATE:** I have a list of integers that represent bits values:

```
bits = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
len(bits) == 30
```

My question is how to add random bit padding so that the length of the bits is 32 and how to remove the padding?
Same in the case when I have the length of bits, let say 20, how to add 4 bit padding so that it become 24 and how to remove back the 4 bit padding?

Comment: This isn't a list of bits, it's a list of integer objects

Comment: What has been your approach so far and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach extracted into a function:

```
import random

def add_padding(seq, num_bits):
    pad_size = num_bits - len(seq) 
    return [random.choice([0, 1]) for _ in range(pad_size)] + seq


bit = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
print(len(bit))

padded = add_padding(bit, 32)
print(len(padded))   # <-- now a 32 bits sequence
```

To remove the padding, you will need to somehow remember the number of bits added to the sequence, and remove them; maybe with slicing:

```
unpadded = padded[num_bits_added:]   # <-- restores the original sequence of bits
```

**[edit]:** to adjust to the closest containing number of bytes:

```
import random

def adjust_a_byte(seq):
    if len(seq) % 8 == 0 and len(seq) > 0:  # an empty sequence will return an 8 bit sequence (all padding)
        pad_size = 0
    else:
        pad_size = 8 * (len(seq) // 8 + 1) - len(seq)
    print('len(seq):', len(seq), 'len(seq) % 8:', len(seq) % 8, 'pad', pad_size)
    return random.choices([0, 1], k=pad_size) + seq

bit = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
print(len(bit))

padded = adjust_a_byte(bit)
print(len(padded)) # <-- now a multiple of 8 bits sequence
```

Comment: Why are you using random.choice like that?

Comment: ok, got it, I am super dumb this morning! Thanks for the heads up

Comment: For python >= 3.6 you can do `random.choices([0, 1] k=pad_size)`

Comment: @Reblochon Masque I have another question. In case I have the length of bit of 7 or 13, how to make the code automatically add 1 for 7 so that it can be 8. Same goes to 13 which can automatically add 3 to make it 16?

Comment: I added an answer to this new question in my answer.

Comment: @Reblochon Masque I get this error `TypeError: choice() got an unexpected keyword argument 'k''

Comment: It is `choices`, not `choice`, and requires python >= 3.6; if that is not your case, use `[random.choice([0, 1]) for _ in range(pad_size)]` as shown earlier

Comment: @Reblochon Masque It's ok. I have found the error. Thank you for the code. Solved the error using this code:`return [random.choice([0, 1]) for _ in range(pad_size)]`

Comment: @Reblochon Masque. Yes. Thank you.

Comment: There was a big bug in the code I posted; the padding was entirely replacing the sequence... Oops! I fixed it and posted the correct code. Sorry about that.